# Java Game of Life implementation: Issues with board updates and infinite loops.

Tags: java, loops, buffer, infinite, conways-game-of-life

Trying to make a [Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) program. Having issues with loops and getting an accurate updating of the game board.

Sorry but I am a beginner so I'm not so good at this. any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
  public class Life {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int gridSize = 200;
        int cellSize = 3;
        Grid grid = new Grid(gridSize, cellSize, "The Game of Life"); 
        grid.setDelay(10); 

        int aliveCells;
        int aliveColor = 1; 
        int deadColor  = 0;

        while (true) {
          for (column = 0;; column++) {
            for (row = 0;; row++) {
              grid.getPos(row, column);
              aliveCells = grid.matchingNeighbors(row, column, aliveColor);
              if (aliveCells == 2 || aliveCells == 3) {
                grid.setPos(row, column, aliveColor);
              } else {
                grid.setPos(row, column, deadColor);
              }
              grid.update();
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish? i.e. why do you need it to be an infinite loop?

Comment: You're probably going to need to give some more information if you want useful answers. Using `while (true){…}` will give you an infinite loop, not sure what else you want.

Comment: You already have an infinite loop..

Comment: also can you provide your HTML or create a fiddle with your code? (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Your for{} statements have no termination. That means that you're never going to get to grid.update();
It looks like you're making a Game of Life-type program?

Comment: @SWPhantom exactly!!!!!! plz help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The comments show off the problem areas. Replace the CAPITAL TEXT with the appropriate variables/numbers.

import java.util.Random;
  public class Life {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int gridSize = 200;
        int cellSize = 3;
        Grid grid = new Grid(gridSize, cellSize, "The Game of Life"); 
        grid.setDelay(10);

```
    int aliveCells;
    int aliveColor = 1; 
    int deadColor  = 0;

    //This creates a gridSizeXgridSize matrix, representing the board.
    int bufferBoard[][] = new int[gridSize][gridSize];

    while (true) {

      //Update the buffer board, represented by an matrix.
      for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; ++column) {
        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; ++row) {
          int isAlive = grid.getPos(row, column); //Assigning current cell's alive-ness to variable to be used later.
          aliveCells = grid.matchingNeighbors(row, column, aliveColor);

          if(isAlive == aliveColor){ //Make all the checks for a living cell.
            if (aliveCells == 2 || aliveCells == 3) {
              bufferBoard[row][column] = aliveColor; //This cell will be alive.
            } else {
              bufferBoard[row][column] = deadColor; //This cell will be dead.
            }
          } else { //The current cell is dead.
            if(aliveCells == 3){
              bufferBoard[row][column] = aliveColor;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      //Time to populate the actual board.
      //Update the buffer board, represented by an matrix.
      for (int column = 0; column < gridSize; ++column) {
        for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; ++row) {
          grid.getPos(row, column);
          if (bufferBoard[row][column] == aliveColor) { //Check the location of the bufferBoard at the specified row and column. 
            grid.setPos(row, column, aliveColor);
          } else {
            grid.setPos(row, column, deadColor);
          }
          grid.update();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a screen that looks like STATIC tv. My lab says this isn't correct.

Comment: Yeah. That sounds right. Without a secondary grid, you're going to have weird things happen. Can you paste the contents of the update() function? Also, pasting more of the main function could be helpful, just so that I can put in exactly what needs to be done with explanations.

Comment: I editted it. hopefully that is what you were asking for

Comment: the lab says that the grid has been defined so i wouldnt need a secondary grid

Comment: do you mean you need me to print sn the game of life?

Comment: damn i just dont know what you mean haha. I think where I am going wrong is that i might need another if-else statement. if the cell was previously dead but has 3 alive neighbor cells, it turns alive. Did i account for that? the gridSize is 200 for both rows and columns

Comment: Just made one. Mikejones0877